# How do I remove specific characters on all strings of a list in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get all items of a column in my SQL database, so I use this code:

```
listOfItems = c.execute('SELECT items FROM TestTable')
listOfItems = c.fetchall()
print(listOfItems)
```

But instead of it printing it like this:

```
test1, test2, test3, test4
```

It is printing like this:

```
[('test1',), ('test2',), ('test3',), ('test4',)]
```

How do I remove those characters?

Comment: `print(','.join(item[0] for item in listOfItems))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in the returned results is a tuple, and `fetchall()` returns a list of rows.

Use a generator to extract the element out of each tuple, and join them with `,`.

```
print(', '.join(row[0] for row in listOfItems))
```